# Does Assets size impact Angular7 Application performance?

Tags: angular, performance, assets

I have to place a lot of help videos in assets folder of my application. Eventually, the size of assets folder is exceeding 250mbs. I wonder, if it will impact the performance of my application or not? I tried to place my videos outside my project but it was giving errors that can't download the video file. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've found 
https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/09/06/angular-performances-part-1/

By compressing you should get smaller packages
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/optimize-angular-bundle-size-in-4-steps-4a3b3737bf45

Hope it helps!